# php only remove wrapper tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I remove only the wrapper tag with preg_replace.

For example: I want to remove p tag from this:

`$html = "<p><div><p>aaaaaa</p></div></p>";`

Output should be: `<div><p>aaaaaa</p></div>`

If input is

`$html = "<p>aaaaaa</p><div>bbbb</div>";`

Output should be: `<p>aaaaaa</p><div>bbbb</div>`

I tried using this regex: `'/<p[^>]*>(.*)<\/p[^>]*>/i'` but it replaced all p tags.

Comment: Your last example doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @KyleFairns It makes sense now that OP has edited the question

Comment: Why do you use regex here? With DOM or any XML approach, you could check, if the supposed "parent" has any "child" elements and if so, remove the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex approach using a recursive pattern.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fSZOh))

```
$htmls = [
    "<p><div><p>aaaaaa</p></div></p>",
    "<div><p>aaaaaa</p></div>",
    "<p>aaaaaa</p><div>bbbbbb</div>",
    "<p>aaaaaa</p><div>bbbbbb</div><p>cccccc</p>",
    "<p>aaaaaa</p><p>bbbbbb</p>",
    "<p>hello<p>aaaaaa</p></p>",
    "<p><p>aaaaaa</p></p>"
];

foreach ($htmls as $i => $html) {
    $without_ptags = preg_replace('~<p>(?:(?R)|.*?)*</p>~', '', $html,2, $count);
    if ($without_ptags === '' && $count == 1) {
        echo "$i => ", substr($html, 3, -4);
    }else{
        echo "$i => not wrapped in p tags";
    }
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0 => <div><p>aaaaaa</p></div>
---
1 => not wrapped in p tags
---
2 => not wrapped in p tags
---
3 => not wrapped in p tags
---
4 => not wrapped in p tags
---
5 => hello<p>aaaaaa</p>
---
6 => <p>aaaaaa</p>
---
```

*Note Parsing HTML with regex is not recommended.  If I can come up with a clever DomDocument approach, I'll add it to my answer.

Until then, my code uses a recursive pattern to replace `<p>...</p>` substrings with an empty string. ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wiRKFZ/1)) `preg_replace()` stores the number of replacements made in `$count`.  If the output string is completely empty and `$count` is `1` then it can be reasoned that the html string was fully nested in a single, parent `<p>` tag.  After making this determination, `substr()` is used to remove the leading `<p>` and the trailing `</p>`.  *note: A replacement limit of `2` is used because 2 or more replacements constitutes a disqualified html string regardless of the output to `$without_ptags`.